# Nested exceptions in c#

Tags: c#, exception

Is there a way to use nested exceptions? I have this code "one the first level":

```
my func()
{
    try
    {
        resp = Web.FormPostRequest(auth_url, authPost, "", url, cookies, type, proxy_string);

    }


    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is xNet.ProxyException)
        {
            throw new xNet.ProxyException();

        }

        if(ex is xNet.NetException)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            throw new xNet.NetException();
            //return false;
        }

    }

}
```

And on the "higher level" I've got this:

```
try
{


    result = myfunc(auth_data[0], auth_data[1], Form1.domain, type, proxy_string);
    break;

}
catch (xNet.NetException ex)
{
    {
        result = false;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return;
    }

}
```

The deal is that debugger always says that excpetion xNet.NetException wasn't handeled at line

```
if(ex is xNet.NetException)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    throw new xNet.NetException();
    //return false;
}
```

in myfunc(). What could it be and how do I resolve this? Thank you!

I change code to simpliest:

```
try
{
    resp = Web.FormPostRequest(auth_url, authPost, "", url, cookies, type, proxy_string);

}


catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

But even now visual stuido says that there is xNet.NetException that wasn't handled.

Comment: why not do a simple `C# MSDN Google search on Nested Exceptions`

Comment: Why are you throwing a new exception of the same type(s) and ignoring all others?  You could just use `throw;` to preserve the original exception and call stack.

Comment: Why are you even doing that?  The entire `catch` block (the first one) is not only superfluous, it's actually *throwing away* useful exception information.

Comment: @David, why is it superfluous? Library that I use has 3 exception types and I need to handle two of them correctly.

Comment: @DStanley, yes thanks, but throw didn't work out (so i tried everyting), I don't know why is this happening.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин But you're _not_ handling them anywhere - you've got some commented out code and creating _new_ exceptions.  If you're not going to do anything then you don;t need  `catch` at all - if you are then best practice would be to let it bubble up to preserve the message(s) and stack trace

Comment: @DStanley I see. I will need to actually implement handling a bit later so now it's just dummies. The problem is that, like it seems, on higher level it's not catching anything and debugger shows me "exception nod handled".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you just catch the specific exceptions you want to catch and let the rest "flow through"?

```
catch (xNet.ProxyException ex) {
     //re-throwing per the comment(s) in a smarter guy's answer.
     throw new Exception("Adding really important info here.",ex);
}
catch (xNet.NetException exToo) {
     //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     //return false;
     //blah .. blah ..
}
```

We do that with SQL exceptions and it works really well. It lets us capture exactly the data we want to capture based on the specific error tossed off by SQL server (sorry for using 'tossed-off' in a stack post ... long day).

There are some rules that govern multiple catch blocks, but [I'm too lazy to type them out here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173162.aspx).

Also - in a blatent attempt to expand this answer to include an un-asked question - the format below is also valid for c# 6

```
catch (Exception ex) when (ex is xNet.ProxyException || ex is xNet.NetException) {                
    //please go away...
}
```

Either way, you catch only what you intend to process, right?  Then, if you need the stack in your outer catch block, take a look at innerException (because we are creating a little nested exception with your new data).

### One Last (Minor) Note (edit)

Per the comments, it seems like the sample code you provide in your original question is throwing one type of error, but the outer catch block is catching a different error type.

**INNER FUNCTION:**

```
throw new xNex.ProxyException();
```

**OUTER FUNCTION:**

```
catch(xNet.NetException ex) ...
```

Maybe that's just because you've made some edits to make this easier to read, but maybe check your code?  Those mistakes are hard to see when you are dialed in!

Comment: I see, but problem is that on the "higher level" It doesn't catch anything and so VS shows me exception wasn't handled error.

Comment: Right ... the re-throw is zero-ing out the stack track attached to the exception?  Can you try taking a look at ex.innerException and re-throwing as outlined above?

Comment: Also - you aren't actually CATCHING the exception you are throwing inside of your sub program.  You throw xNet.ProxyException, but your outer method catches ONLY xNet.NetException.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: wait a minute, why I'am not catching that exception? Also, now I'll take a look at innerexception and report results.

Comment: Will add to the answer (at the bottom) if that's cool... hard to explain in comments ;)

Comment: innerException is null and stack wasn't zeroed.

Comment: thanks for your time! You was so right in the end. Yes, I made some changes in the code and didn't noticed that. Much thanks once again!

Comment: Cool!  Just one more little thing ... the debugger can be setup to break whenever you THROW an exception (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx).  That doesn't mean your outer catch doesn't deal with the ex, it's just the debugger's way of saying 'hey ... did you want to take a look at this?'

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a *really good reason* for creating new exception and swallowing all but those two types I would just change your `catch` block to rethrow the original exception in all cases:

```
catch (xNet.ProxyException ex)
{
    // is there something you want to do here?
    throw;  // let the caller handle all exceptions.
}
catch(xNet.NetException ex)
{
     // is there something you want to do here?
    throw;  // let the caller handle all exceptions.
}
catch
{
    throw;  // let the caller handle all exceptions.
}
```

If you're not going to do anything in either of the handlers, then you can just remove the entire `catch` block and let the exception bubble up naturally.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I resolve this?

Well, the first thing you should do is remove this entire `catch` block:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is xNet.ProxyException)
    {
        throw new xNet.ProxyException();
    }
    if(ex is xNet.NetException)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        throw new xNet.NetException();
        //return false;
    }
}
```

Not only is it not actually doing anything to handle the exception, but it's explicitly *throwing away* the exception and replacing it with one that doesn't have any of the information about the error that occurred.

So the resulting method would simply be:

```
void MyFunc()
{
    resp = Web.FormPostRequest(auth_url, authPost, "", url, cookies, type, proxy_string);
}
```

If the method *does* have some information to add to the exception, then you should at least preserve the original exception as well:

```
void MyFunc()
{
    try
    {
        resp = Web.FormPostRequest(auth_url, authPost, "", url, cookies, type, proxy_string);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // do something here?
        throw new SomeExceptionType(ex);
    }
}
```

Or, if there's no new information to add (but still something meaningful to *do*), at least re-throw the original exception:

```
void MyFunc()
{
    try
    {
        resp = Web.FormPostRequest(auth_url, authPost, "", url, cookies, type, proxy_string);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // do something here
        throw;
    }
}
```

But unless there's something you can do to actually *handle* or in any way *respond to* the exception, don't even bother catching it.  It should only be caught by code which *can* meaningfully handle it.